# Formatting text file into columns with sprintf with C

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a basic text file I point my program at to run that has numbers line by line such as:

```
3
30
300
3000
30000
300000
3000000
30000000
300000000
-3
-30
-300
-3000
-30000
-300000
-3000000
-30000000
-300000000
```

and I need to print them out into evenly spaced columns and I want them to fit into 40 characters (4 columns wide).  I want to use the sprintf function to do this.  So basically print each number out plus 2 spaces for formatting and fit within 40 characters total.  So far this is what I have.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int a, b, num[1000], nums = 0;
    char str[40];
    FILE *pt;
    int col, max, w;

    if(argc < 2){
      printf("Usage %s <No Files>\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }

   if((pt = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
     printf("Unable to open %s for reading.\n", argv[1]);
     return 1;
   }

   while(fscanf(pt, "%d", &b) == 1){
     num[nums++] = b;
   }

   w = sprintf(str, "%*d", num[a]);

   if(max < w){
     col = 40 / (max + 2);
     printf("%d  %d\n", w, num[a]);
   }

   return 0;

 }
```

I just get garbage when I point it to the text file mentioned in the above.  Any advice?

Comment: A specifier like `"%*d"` requires two arguments, one for how many places and one for the integer value. You're providing one. You should probably eliminate the `*` part if you're not intending to do that.

Comment: Why not just use `%40d` or `%-40d`?

Comment: *"So basically print each number out [4 of them?] plus 2 spaces for formatting and fit within 40 characters total.*" How is that possible if your longest string with be `10-chars` (e.g. `-300000000`). `10+2+10+2+10+2+10 = 48`??

Comment: The reason it is unclear is *"I need to print them out into evenly spaced columns"* is mutually exclusive if you are failing to provide an even column width and spacing for each line.

Comment: Also -- out of curiosity - what value are you using for `max`? How do you spit `18` numbers into lines with `4` evenly spaced columns? Last line gets only `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my second answer for the same question, but this answer more close to the topic - here output is made to the string with `sprintf`.

So, lets we have array of numbers `int num[1000]` and we need to print `nums` of them to several string (length is limited by value `stringMaxLength`) using formatting as columns with width depending on length of number representation (maximum number in the array).

The following snippet has comments for all operations

```
// string that will be made from numbers
const int stringMaxLength = 120;
char str[stringMaxLength + 1]; // just one string

// find longest number considering sign
char buff[20] = { 0 };
int maxNumWidth = 0, numWidth;
int n;
for (n = 0; n < nums; n++)
{
    numWidth = strlen(_itoa(num[n], buff, 10));
    if (numWidth > maxNumWidth)
        maxNumWidth = numWidth;
}

int colWidth = maxNumWidth + 1; // a column size with one space between columns
int colNum = stringMaxLength / colWidth; // number of columns in one string
int s, i; // i - nums counter, s - strings counter
for (i = 0, s = 1; i < nums; s++) // loop counts strings but with condition for nums
{
    int sizeCnt = 0; // start making new string str
    // loop works while there are numbers and the line is not filled completely 
    while (i < nums)
    {
        // add next number (column) to the string and increase string size
        sizeCnt += sprintf(str + sizeCnt, "%*d", colWidth, num[i++]);
        if (i % colNum == 0)  // if string has colNum numbers it is full
        {
            break; // stop while loop 
        }
    }
    // next string is ready and can be used
    printf("%d : %s\n", s, str); // e.g. for output
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to look for a solution especially geared towards sprintf.  I really appreciate the help.  You guys are the best!

Comment: @David C. Rankin thank you for your help as well.  I have a much better understanding over all what i need to do.

Answer (score 5):

To print N numbers in 4 columns with width 10 characters use `printf("%10d")` inside the loop that add new line (`\n`) after each 4th printing, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= nums; i++)
{
    printf("%10d", num[i-1]); // or printf("%-10d", num[i-1]);
    if (i % 4 == 0)
        printf("\n"); // or putchar ('\n')
}
```

sign `-` in the format `%-10d` change alignment.

As you see `sprinf` is not used here, I use `printf` for each number to print the value at screen (standard output).

**UPDATE:**

If you want to find optimal width of the column, and use it for output, e.g. using the number of digits in your biggest number (let it be `maxValue` an integer value found in the array `num`), you can find the minimum required number of digits (let it be `minWidth`), like:

```
char buff[20] = {0};
int minWidth = strlen(_itoa(maxValue,buff,10));
```

and then change the printing loop like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= nums; i++)
{
    printf("%*d", minWidth + 1, num[i - 1]);
    if (i % 4 == 0) putchar('\n');
}
```

here vlaue `minWidth + 1` will be used in format specifier `%*d` instead of `*`, and `+1` is used for minimum separation between columns in one space (of course, there can be 2 or 3).

Finally, having the column width calculated, you can find the number of column for your screen and use this value for starting new line, e.g.:

```
const int screenWidth = 80;
int colWidth = minWidth + 2; // here 2 is added for minimum separation of columns
int colNum = screenWidth / colWidth;

for (int i = 1; i <= nums; i++)
{
    printf("%*d", colWidth, num[i - 1]);
    if ( !(i % colNum) ) putchar('\n'); // !(i % colNum) is the same to i % colNum == 0
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, putchar is simpler function and fit better here

Comment: Well, it's more a "why use the very complex *variadic* `printf` function to output a single-char?" The correct tools there are `putchar` and `fputc`. But note I qualified it as a *nit* -- it's small potatoes and what you are doing is correct, but when teaching new C programmers, you always want to provoke thought about what the most efficient tool for the job is `:)` - you get the vote either way...